# Total no. of balanced parenthesis with maximum nesting of $d$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

$C_n$(the $n^{th}$ catalan number) counts the number of expressions containing $n$ pairs of parenthesis which are correctly matched
How to count the possibilities if the maximum nesting level is fixed to $d$?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is described in several equivalent ways in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/the-catalan-numbers-regular-languages-and-orthogonal-polynomials/).  For fixed $d$ the corresponding sequence $C_{d,n}$ satisfies a linear recurrence, and its generating function is "the $d^{th}$ convergent" of a continued fraction representation of the generating function of the Catalan numbers.  Explicitly,

$$C_{d,n} = \frac{1}{d+1} \sum_{i=1}^d 2 \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{d+1} \left( 2 \cos \frac{\pi i}{d+1} \right)^{2n}.$$

(The indexing may be off by one.)