# Permutations for a set of rules

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question is from - http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2015/zio2015/zio2015-question-paper.pdf - Q.2

I tried solving it but I have no clue how to go about doing it.

The question says that a railway company occupied a new yard. Every train must enter the yard and leave it which happens when the yard manager gives the command 'enter' or 'leave'. The train leave in a first in last out manner.  There are N number of trains. The company requires that no train may wait at the yard for more than K instructions

Calculate the number of ways the yard manager can give the set of instruction.

For example if N=2 and K=0 then the only way to do it is enter,leave,enter,leave same if K=1
If k=2 then the other method possible is enter,enter,leave,leave

(a) N = 6 and K = 8.
(b) N = 8 and K = 4.
(c) N = 10 and K = 4.

Comment: If you want a general solution, you might get some ideas from [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/total-no-of-balanced-parenthesis-with-maximum-nesting-of-d) and the link provided in Qiaochu's answer.

Comment: That just went over the top of my head. :D

Answer (score 0):

A general solution seems perhaps possible but not trivial. If you just want to solve those three cases without electronic aids, you can approach them individually.

The problem can be formulated as counting the number of strings with $N$ pairs of matching parentheses such that no parenthesis "stays open" longer than $K$.

(a) $N=6$, $K=8$. Here the $K$ constraint is rather weak; the only strings that violate it are the ones where the train that enters first leaves last. Thus the result here is the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_6$ of all strings with six pairs of matching parentheses minus the number $C_5$ that counts the ways in which the other $5$ trains can be instructed if the first one leaves last, yielding $C_6-C_5=132-42=90$.

(b) $N=8$, $K=4$ and (c) $N=10$, $K=4$. In both cases $K=4$, and for this case we can set up a manageable recurrence relation. Let $a_N$ be the desired numbers (for $K=4$), and consider the $N$-th train as the first in line. It can either enter and immediately leave, which leaves $a_{N-1}$ possibilities for the remaining $N-1$ trains. Or it can enter, then the second train enters, and then they both leave, which leaves $a_{N-2}$ possibilities for the remaining $N-2$ trains. Or it can enter, wait for two trains to enter and leave, and then leave. The two trains can enter and leave in $2$ different ways, and the remaining $N-3$ trains have $a_{N-3}$ possibilities. Thus, in total we have

$$a_N=a_{N-1}+a_{N-2}+2a_{N-3}$$

for $N\ge3$, with initial values $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$. The result is [OEIS sequence A077947](https://oeis.org/A077947) (that page gives some interesting properties which might perhaps provide some indications for solving the general problem), and the desired values are $a_8=146$ and $a_{10}=585$. (I took them from the OEIS page but it would be easy enough to calculate them using the recurrence relation.)

Comment: Unfortunately, http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2015/zio2015/zio2015-solutions.pdf says that a) has the answer 90. Also what do you mean by very weak?

Comment: @archit: Sorry, I had a mistake in part (a); I hadn't taken into account that the other five trains can do what they want while the first one waits; I corrected that. By "weak" I just mean that it's not that much of a constraint, that it's hard to violate because one train has to wait for the entire available time in order to violate it. (I've changed it to "rather weak" because it turned out to be a bit stronger than I first realized. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I believe I got this now. I was also having trouble with 4th question of the same pdf. Should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: @archit: Yes, you should, and I'll be happy to try to answer it :-)